# AssertionError: b' Trabalhando com classes de testes em Django (TDD)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, testes

Estou iniciando meus estudos de testes com Django e estou recebendo um erro onde aparentemente não deveria, tanto que a descrição do traceback me deixa bastante confuso.

Possuo uma classe que testa se o retorno da minha view é compatível com o seu valor preestabelecido, algo simples que se parece com isso:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...

class TestMinhaView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.url = reverse('core:spy')
        self.client = Client()

    def test_get(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.content, 'Dados Corretos!')
```

Feita para testar o retorno desta View:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
...

class MinhaView(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Dados Corretos!')
```

Após a modelagem das classes, é hora de testar! Digito no terminal:

```
manage.py test
```

e então ele me retorna o curioso erro no seu Traceback:

```
self.assertEqual(response.content, 'Dados Corretos!')
AssertionError: b'Dados Corretos!' != 'Dados Corretos!'
```

Este b me deixa curioso. O que poderia ser? Pois não consigo encontrar um erro lógico já que as informações na classe de teste e funcional são exatamente as mesmas.

Agradeço antecipadamente a paciência de quem se dispor, e perdão se for de um nível iniciante. Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta colocar `self.assertEqual(response.content, 'Dados Corretos!.decode("utf-8")')` ou `self.assertEqual(response.content.decode("utf-8"), 'Dados Corretos!')`.

Esse b na frente quer dizer que a string está codificada em bytes e não em caracteres unicode, por isso sugeri usar o `decode`.

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela explicação e resposta, sua segunda alternativa funcionou! (a primeira ele considerou a instrução .decode como parte da string literal não o executando).
Nunca pensei que a resposta sairia tão rápido, em menos de 10 minutos! Haha, obrigado!

Comment: na verdade a primeira foi um "typo" meu, era pra ter escrito 'Dados Corretos!'.decode("utf-8"). Mas se deu certo do outro jeito isso nem importa

Comment: Assim também não dá certo, pois ao que percebi ele é aninhado e exige que a string tenha passado pelo encode antes de se usar o decode. 'Dados Corretos!'.decode("utf-8") me retorna um erro dizendo que o objeto não possui tal método.